# Как реализовать увеличение содержимого экрана пальцами?

Tags: android, android-fragment, gestures

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать увеличение экрана раздвижением пальцев или двойным нажатием по экрану? есть ли какие-то стандартные функции? В приложении одно активити, все остальное фрагменты. как реализовать данную функцию в фрагменте?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: а для текста? например как использовать pinch zoom, не в курсе?

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется увеличить все вьюшки фрагмента - то скорей всего никак. Это стандартные фичи WebView.

Comment: TextView, ImageView?